# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') unhandledRejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I use the stock command in my sales bot, I get this:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') unhandledRejection

my code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const db = require("quick.db")
const config = require("../config.json")
module.exports = {
    
    name: "stock", // Coloque o nome do comando do arquivo
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        message.delete()
        const embederro = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Erro - Permissão`)
        .setDescription(`Você não tem permissão para isto!`)
        .setColor(config.cor)
        .setFooter({text:`${config.nomebot} - Todos os direitos reservados.`})
        if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embederro] }).then(msg => {
                    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 5000)
                })
                const embednprod = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Erro - Sistema de Estoque")
                .setDescription("Você não tem nenhum produto adicionado, utilize \`[add]\` para criar o produto!")
                .setColor(config.cor)
        if(db.all().length == 0) return message.channel.send({embeds: [embednprod]}).then(msg => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)
        })
const itens = db.all().map(item => `ID: ${item.ID} | QUANTIDADE: ${item.data.conta.length || "0"}`)
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Estoque")
.setDescription(`\`\`\`${itens.join("\n\n")}\`\`\``)
.setColor(config.cor)
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]}).then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)
})

    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that some of the items returned by db.all() do not have a data property, which would cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` before in my code many times before and it usually means that the you're trying to access data from an object that does not yet exist in memory.

In your code that you posted, the line that is causing the error is likely to be:

```js
const itens = db.all().map(item => `ID: ${item.ID} | QUANTIDADE: ${item.data.conta.length || "0"}`)
```

Since you're not properly checking to see if it exists before outputting data. I see you're using a logical OR for this but sometimes that doesn't properly work as expected.

To fix this, replace the check with a ternary operator to see if `item.data` is defined before accessing its properties. You can modify the line to look something like this:

```js
const itens = db.all().map(item => `ID: ${item.ID} | QUANTIDADE: ${item.data && item.data.conta ? item.data.conta.length : "0"}`)
```

This checks to see if `item.data` exists and if it has the `conta` property before accessing its `length`. If either of these properties is resolved as being `undefined`, it will default to `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to used === operator so its match value and check type too.

try to replacing if condition like below:

```
if(db.all().length == 0 || undefined) return message.channel.send({embeds: [embednprod]}).then(msg => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)
        })
```